# Beamer: How to create a bigger footline?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I want to create a relatively large footline in Beamer like this one:[image]

What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Comment: Near 80 characters in a line? Very strange for  a `beamer` example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the font template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\Large}

\title{foo}
\author{baz}
\institute{foobar}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{frame}{Test}{Subtest}
    a frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```